# How to compare 2 directories and list only the files which are different?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code that compares 2 directories and outputs an indicator to indicate the difference between the directory files.

```
$Folder1 = "source_folder_path"
$Folder2 = "dest_folder_path"
function Get-Directories ($path)
{
    $PathLength = $path.length
    Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | % {
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RelativePath -Value $_.FullName.substring($PathLength+1)
        $_
    }
}

Compare-Object (Get-Directories $Folder1) (Get-Directories $Folder2) -Property RelativePath | Sort RelativePath, Name -desc
```

This gives me an output like this:

[image]

The side indicator `<=` means the file or folder exists only in the source. i.e., missing in the destination.
The side indicator `=>` means the file or folder exists only in the destination. i.e., missing in the source.

However, i only want to list the files that are different (i.e. dont exist in the directory), and only different by Name. Currently, the code above compares the file with the extension, and if the extension is different, e.g. image1.jpg vs image1.png, it will mark them as different. however, i dont want that and instead i would like it to ignore the extension.
i.e.

```
image1.png vs image1.jpg = no difference, dont list it
image1.png in folder 1 but not in folder 2 = list it
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Resolve the input folders to full paths first.
$Folder1 = Convert-Path $Folder1
$Folder2 = Convert-Path $Folder2

Compare-Object (Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse $Folder1) `
               (Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse $Folder2) `
               -Property {
                 # Determine the relative path and then compare
                 # the directory path + the file *base* name.
                 $relativePath = $_.FullName.Substring(
                   ($Folder1.Length, $Folder2.Length)[$_.FullName.StartsWith($Folder2, 'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase')]
                 )
                 [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($relativePath) + '/' +
                   [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($relativePath)
               } -PassThru |
  Select-Object Name, Directory
```

The above doesn't just list the name (which could be ambiguous), but also the directory in which a given unique file was found.

Comment: i see. if i want to export this to csv, it'd be as simple as `Select-Object Name, Directory |
  Export-Csv -Path .\filecomp.csv -NoTypeInformation` right?

Comment: @Cataster: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, compare two folders using the basename property:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\admin\foo\dir1

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          11/24/2020  4:54 PM              4 image1.png
-a---          11/24/2020  4:55 PM              4 image2.png

    Directory: C:\Users\admin\foo\dir2

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          11/24/2020  4:54 PM              4 image1.jpg
```

```
compare-object (dir dir1) (dir dir2) -property basename

basename SideIndicator
-------- -------------
image2   <=
```